# How to remove text after last space and the space as well in VBA? And how to call the SAME function in SUB()?

Tags: vba, excel

> My column has values something like
>
> XXXX YYYY ZZZZ.xlsx
>
> and I want them to be
>
> XXXX YYYY

Please let me know if you have any questions or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with the following code:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data on column A
For I = 1 To LastRow 'loop through column A data
ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value = RemoveAfterLastSpace(ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value) 'replace the new values of Column A
Next I
End Sub

Function RemoveAfterLastSpace(Txt As String) As String
Dim IFOUND As Integer
Dim I As Integer
    IFOUND = 0
    For I = Len(Txt) To 1 Step -1
        If ((Mid(Txt, I, 1) = " ") And (IFOUND = 0)) Then IFOUND = I: Exit For
    Next I
    If (IFOUND <> 0) Then RemoveAfterLastSpace = Left(Txt, IFOUND - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is very helpful and meets my need.

Comment: @sat please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped you? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I marked yours as an answer. I have a quick question, How to tweak this code to make it work for Column "B" . I did this little tweak to the code, but unfortunately it didn't work "LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: @sat You would change the "A" to "B" but then also replace Cells(I,1).value with Cells(I,2).value (there are two instances to be replaced) then it should work...

Comment: It works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're asking:

```
Sub stripFromLastSpace()
Dim inputString As String
Dim lastSpace As Integer
Dim outputString As String
Dim someRng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set someRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

For Each cell In someRng.Cells
    inputString = cell.Value
    lastSpace = InStrRev(inputString, " ")
    outputString = Left(inputString, lastSpace - 1)
    cell.Value = outputString
Next cell

End Sub
```

I used [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/string-manipulation-summary) to make my answer. Be warned, this is a very simple example which will not handle strings without a space in them. It will err out upon encountering such a string.

In most other languages I would just use a regex match to do what you want. Unfortunately, I've never had good experiences with the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` reference that is built into VBA. Instead I use the `InStrRev` function to find the position of the last space in the input string. Once we have this, use `Left` to grab the left side of the string up to the character before the last space.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Highly appreciated.